# Google Chrome - Unwanted Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, google-chrome

From one angular $http ajax call two requests appeared on the server in Google Chrome normal state. *(not always, sometimes everything is ok)*.  In incognito mode everything always work fine.

I used the Chrome Developer Tool for the investigation, but still don't have the answer. Please find the attached images and angularjs script bellow.

*(I uploaded the Chrome dev tools screens. Please someone give me a description what that phenomenon is.)*

**Angular part:**

```
 $http({
   method: "POST",
   url: "handler",
   cache: false,
   headers: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   data: _data,
 }).then(function Success(response) {
 ...
```

[Normal state image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTGHM.jpg)
[Abnormal state main image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUOMF.jpg)
[Details for the first request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtuWu.jpg)
[Details for the second request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6A89.jpg)

How can I skip the unwanted call?

Comment: Usually this is a problem with preventing a default call from a form.